# Do we need to sign .apk file everytime we update it on playstore?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have already signed my app the first time with this command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore android/app/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

So I was wondering if I have to do it again every time I update my app because whenever I try to repeat this command I'm getting error saying the key already exist

Edit : what's the difference between theses two commands

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: Generating a key and signing an apk using that key are different operations. The key has to be generated only once. The signature has to be done for each apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating key is one time process, After that you have to sign your apk every time with same generated key. You can do this in android studio easily. Refer the apk signing process at developer site [APK signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)